# Question on Cochrane–Orcutt estimation. Can I simply use inverse of the lag operator?

Tags: regression, time-series, autoregressive

I came across the [Cochrane–Orcutt estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochrane%E2%80%93Orcutt_estimation), which is concerned with regression-type estimates in cases where errors are AR(1) correlated. My question is whether I can formally apply the inverse of the $(1-\theta L)$ operator, where $\theta$ is the parameter to be fitted and $L$ is the lag operator, to the whole equation to get back to iid errors, and whether the fitting procedure I can see in Wikipedia can be viewed as a first-order approximation of this.

So the relationship we are interested in is:
$$
y_t=\alpha+\beta\cdot x_t + \epsilon_t=\beta\cdot x_t + \left(1-\theta L\right)\eta_t\quad (1)
$$

Where $x_t$ is the independent variable, $y_t$ is the dependent variable, $\epsilon_t$ is first-order correlated noise and $\eta_t$ is hypothetical uncorrelated noise. Wikipedia page suggests that the way to proceed in such situation is to focus on the problem of the following shape instead:

$$
y_t-\rho y_{t-1}=(1-\rho)\alpha+\beta\left(x_t-\rho x_{t-1}\right)+\xi_t \quad (2)
$$

Where $\xi_t$ is another, presumably uncorrelated, noise.

**Question:** Can I view this as an outcome of applying:
$$
\left(1-\theta L\right)^{-1}=1+\theta L+\theta^2 L^2+\theta^3 L^3 +\dots
$$
to equation (1)? i.e. Is Equation (2) the linear approximation of:

$$
y_t+\theta y_{t-1}+\theta^2 y_{t-2}+\dots=(1+\theta+\theta^2+\dots)\alpha+\beta\left(x_t+\theta x_{t-1}+\theta^2 x_{t-2}+\dots\right)+\eta_t \quad (3)
$$

Comment: The formula (1) defines a linear regression with MA(1) error, not AR(1). Indeed if $\epsilon_t$ is AR(1) we have  $(1- \rho L) \epsilon_t =\zeta_t$ where $\zeta_t$ is white noise. The regression with AR(1) error can be written formally using a fraction as in  $y_t = \alpha + \beta x_t + 1 / (1 - \rho L) \zeta_t$.

Comment: @Yves thanks. I think it completely solves my question